# Eclipse Kepler: Change default account to use when committing with egit?

Tags: java, eclipse, github, egit, eclipse-kepler

I have two git accounts - one personal and one for work.

Whenever I commit something with egit, the default account used is my work account. I have to make sure every single commit that I change it to my personal one.

However, today I forgot to do so and it commit and pushed to my repository with my work account.

How would I go about changing the default account being used when committing on egit?

Answer (score 0):

You can change this in the Eclipse preferences. Go into the `Window` tab and at the bottom of the menu list, click `Preferences`. Then expand `Team`, followed by `Git` and finally select `Configuration`. Once that's done, change `user.name` to your name and `user.email` to your email address.

---

Just so you know, there are also *way* more recent versions than Kepler... They also have more features and bug fixes. From most recent to least recent:

1. Neon
2. Mars
3. Luna
4. Kepler

Each version of these can be downloaded on the [Eclipse download page](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/Neon/M4A%20%22Eclipse%20for%20Java%20Developers%20Neon%20M4A) (Eclipse IDE for Java Developers), just select the release you would like to obtain.